# do_table or ignore_table alternatives on MariaDB Galera Multi-Master

Tags: mysql, mariadb, binlog, multi-master, master-master-replication

As far as I can see, there are no `do_table` or `ignore_table` configs in MariaDB Galera multi-master (master-master) to skip or ignore specific tables. And there are only `binlog_do_db` and `binlog_ignore_db` options, which only work for databases.

I have multiple servers in my formation, and I only want to sync two tables in each server database. Other tables' data should be intact.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "intact", do you mean that they never change?  And are already "in sync"?  In that case, it does not matter whether you let Galera handle them.

Galera is not designed for partial replication.  Galera and any other true multi-master needs to have *all* tables existing on the Masters, ready for failover.

Old-fashioned Replication is designed for partial replication, but you must use it with caution.  Cf `replicate-do-table`.

**Engine**

Do some research.  Since Galera cannot correctly handle MyISAM or MEMORY engines, see if they are completely excluded from replication by default.  Consider creating the 'intact' tables as `ENGINE=MyISAM`.

**Definition**

To get around the GDPR without really violating it, can you consider the "Cluster" as a "single computer"?

Comment: Other tables are regular tables, and in this scenario, they don't need any sync mechanism. By old-fashioned replication, you mean master-slave replication, right? My goal is for each server to be a master and replica simultaneously.

Comment: @Roham - What is the harm in letting the "intact" tables replicate?

Comment: It will violate GDPR law.

Comment: @Roham you may be able to use two-way master-slave replication, i.e. master-master replication instead. Just note there are a couple of "gotchas" with that approach.

Comment: @dbdemon - I assumed he was talking about replication within the cluster -- Galera only replicates everything from every node to every other node.  (I think.)

Comment: @Roham - I added a couple more thoughts; see if either will lead to a solution.